# Canvas drawImage

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I have the following issue:

When I draw multiple images on to a canvas a part of the existing canvas becomes blank, depending of the amount of images I draw to it. Basically I need the logic in order to take a snapshot of a map. Since the map I am using is lazy loading, I must save the single chunks of my map and draw them onto a canvas to get the whole map. Perhaps each chunk/part of the map has the size 256x256

**For better understanding:**
If my map consists of 4 chunks, it works completely fine, but if my map consists of 8 chunks (2 rows, 4 columns each), a part of the canvas gets blank after the fourth picture was drawn. After the fifth image was drawn it even looks worse:

**Example:**

After third image being added:
[image]

After fourth picture being added:
[image]

After fifth picture being added:
[image]

Image 1:

```
x:  768 px,  y:  256 px
src: 
https://maps2.wien.gv.at/basemap/geolandbasemap/normal/google3857/15/11357/17870.png
```

Image 2:

```
x:  512 px,  y:  256 px
src: 
https://maps1.wien.gv.at/basemap/geolandbasemap/normal/google3857/15/11357/17869.png
```

Image 3:

```
x:  256 px,  y:  256 px
src: 
https://maps.wien.gv.at/basemap/geolandbasemap/normal/google3857/15/11357/17868.png
```

Image 4:

```
x:  0 px,  y:  256 px
src: 
https://maps4.wien.gv.at/basemap/geolandbasemap/normal/google3857/15/11357/17867.png
```

Image 5:

```
x: 768 px,  y:  0 px
src: 
https://maps1.wien.gv.at/basemap/geolandbasemap/normal/google3857/15/11356/17870.png
```

**Here is my code:**.

```
// heights and widths are both 2d arrays which have the image element at
// index 0 and the    size at index 1. So in the widths I the width of
// the image/map part is [1] and the same goes for the heights array


    var concat = document.createElement("canvas");
    var concatCtx = concat.getContext("2d");

    // this part of the code is dependant on much of my other logic, but you can assume 
    //that the width and the height are determined correctly. So for instance if my map 
    //consists of 8 chunks, the height will be 512px and the width 1024px
    concat.width = currOffset + 256;
    concat.height = currOffsetHeight +  256;


 heights.forEach((height, i) => {
      let el = height[0];
      el.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
      let heightOffset = height[1];
      let widthTransform = widths.find(w => w[0] === el);
      
      let widthOffset = widthTransform[1];
   
      
      el.onload = () => {
            loadedCntr += 1;
            
            console.warn('x: ',widthOffset, 'px, ', 'y: ', heightOffset, 'px')
            // drawImage(image: CanvasImageSource, sx: number, sy: number, sw: number, sh: number, dx: number, dy: number, dw: number, dh: number): void;
            
            concatCtx.drawImage(el, 0, 0, 256, 256, widthOffset, heightOffset, 256, 256);
              console.log(el.src)
              console.log(concat.toDataURL("image/png"))

              

              if(loadedCntr === heights.length)
              {
                // when all map parts are concatenated proceed
              }
            }
      el.src = `${el.src}`;
    })
    }
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't suggest an error (you don't need to use clipped coordinates though as the offset, width&height seem to be the same always). Can you provide an example which clearly showcases the issue you're having?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you mean. Height/Width stay always the same, therefore i replaced it with 256. But the offset is dynamic. In the background the actual map is represented by x images, that depend on the zoom level, the current poistion etc. Those pictures dont't follow a specific order and are positioned via translate: transform3d(x, y, 0). Since I do not need the specific  coordinates when I want to concetanate map, i just loop over all images and save there x and y offsets in widths and heights array properly.